# Looking for a werewolf movie (comedy) where the cameraman is shot

Tags: story-identification, movie, werewolf

I have not seen this myself, but a colleague talked about it and I got curious.

The intro has a boy visiting Eastern Europe with his father and is bitten by a werewolf while waiting outside when his father is visiting a brothel. 
Presumably they are both from the US, but they may be from England also?

Later in the movie there is a scene with bullets flying where the movie goes black because the cameraman is shot.

I assume that the shot cameraman is sufficiently unique to identify the movie.  If not I will try to get more details.

Comment: a cameraman shot could indicate a Mel Brooks movie (usually at least 1 fight overflows into the movie's set and crew, see spaceballs)

Comment: @sigber: Did you ever get a chance to check out *Full Moon High*?

Comment: I finally gave up on finding a dvd or streaming and found it on youtube.  My colleague confirmed that this was the one and I have flagged it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"[Full Moon High](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Moon_High)"(1981)? This is just a guess because I've not seen it. I remember seeing the trailer for it though.

> A teenager goes on a trip to Transylvania with his father and gets bitten by a werewolf. Made ageless, he attempts to put his life back together a couple of decades later by enrolling in high school. The basic premise of the movie is that he tries to keep his secret from the school and his girlfriend with theoretically comedic results. The movie was filmed partially at John Burroughs Senior High School in the city of Burbank, California, in the summer of 1979.

*[Nightmare Movies: Horror on Screen Since the 1960s](https://books.google.com/books?id=fKaam297D2cC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22full%20moon%20high%22%20cameraman%20shot&source=bl&ots=eVkwQSPvd_&sig=CukQna7_iN84OlyZUGIGoR3Q8Qc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi--666i8PWAhXD0FQKHTIECggQ6AEIRjAK#v=onepage&q=%22full%20moon%20high%22%20cameraman%20shot&f=false)* mentions the cameraman being shot:

> Obviously undertaken as something of a lark, the film manages to send up its own cheapness, as when a character 'accidentally' shoots the cameraman during a climax and the screen does black while a voice-over tess [sic] us about the terrific special effects scene we're missing.